# How to enter data in mongodb array at specific position such that if there is only 2 data in array and I want to insert at 5, then rest data is null

Tags: arrays, database, mongodb, mongoose

This is the original data that I want to edit -

```
"Languages" : [
        "English",
        "French"
    ],
```

And this is what I want to achieve by inserting the data such that it will leave 2 null values if there is empty spaces when entering the data at position 5 and if there is only 1 empty space then it should only add 1 null data in the array and then it should add Tamil into the array -

```
"Languages" : [
        "English",
        "French",
        null,
        null,
        "Tamil"
    ],
```

This is what I tried -

```
$push: {
       "Languages" : {
            $each: ["Tamil"],
            $position: 4
        }
}
```

Comment: Your example data already has `"Tamil"` in it. So you want to _**move**_ it to position 4? Or fix your example data. And since you want `null` inserted in all positions between the last and the new value, obviously `push each position` doesn't work. Show what you have actually tried to solve this. We're not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: You could do `$each: [null, null, "Tamil"]`